# Is there anyway ? to communicate across regions from k8s service in Azure using DNS or anything else (but Loadbalancer not be used here)

Tags: azure, azure-networking

I have two services,
    serviceA -> in "akswestus2" and 
    "serviceB" -> in "akseastus2"

How to make connection from Service A to Service B? using DNS or something elseazure ?

Answer (score 0):

Your AKS instances operate as completely separate Kuberenetes clusters, so you have to treat these applications as communicating externally, rather than trying to do at as if they are in a shared cluster.

Given that, how would you normally access a service that is external? You can setup vnet peering to connect your two virtual networks together and then expose application B to application A using whatever API's your application provides. You can setup DNS to allow name based resolution of the service using Azure DNS or your own DNS provider.